# Keeping my database updated every 30 minutes using Log files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

I have a situation where i get a full nightly backup and trans log backup every 30minutes starts at 7:00 am ends at 2 am . I need to restore them every 30 minutes into a database and replicate this data into another database , so every next 30 minutes I should be able to restore the log files and keep the database in usable state to replicate this data to another database . I think we cannot use the database while restoring log files, but is there any process to deal with this kind of situation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to use AlwaysOn

Comment: So is there an option while restoring which says always on ? I'm not sure , sorry if I'm wrong

Comment: No its a technology which you can implement in SQLServer

Comment: Does this allow me to replicate the data into another database while restoring is happening every 30 minutes ?

Comment: It takes care of your requirement .You can read about more on this here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx

Comment: Thank you . I will take a look into it.